# Cultural Fit Interview - good idea to mention that I have interviewed with the same company before?

Tags: interviewing, company-culture, united-kingdom

I've applied to a company, lets call them 'A', before and got through the final round. The final round is usually a cultural fit interview with the hiring teams. 4 months ago I was in one, but the role was cut so I didn't actually land the job. However, HR gave me a follow up call to explain that it wasn't anything negative during the process itself, that the teams quite liked me, just the simple fact that headcount was cut.

Now I find myself with another cultural fit interview within the same company but in a completely different team. Is it a good idea to mention my prior interview?

Comment: It's dicey.  Unless you know how this team feels about the other team, it could get you into trouble.  IF you're interviewing with Joe, and telling him what a great guy "Jim" from the last time was, it will be great if Jim and Joe are friends, but if not, it could work against you.  Try to do some recon on how the two teams get along before doing this.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere yes

Comment: I actually destroyed my chances with one company by mentioning it when interviewing for a different position that "Joe from team X" had interviewed me before. It turns out there was major clashing between the two teams, and knowing that I had once interviewed with Joe was somehow a sin in the eyes of my interviewer (it came across in the way the conversation carried on from there)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask the person who gave you a follow-up, using the original email in which they told you why they did not keep you, if there's one .

If you had the chance of stumbling upon a nice enough HR person that he took the time to tell you why they did not retain you, that person will probably be nice enough to answer this one. Particularly, if you might be one of his/her colleague in a few weeks.